# In JMP 11, how do you tabulate how many rows are selected, excluded, and hidden?

Tags: sas-jmp

I have data where some are either (A)Hidden and Excluded or (B) Labeled or (C) Both.

Is there a way that I can generate a table which summarizes how many rows belong to Groups A, B, & C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an easy way to do this interactively but if you are comfortable running some JSL script, this seems to work:

```
hiddenAndExcluded = 0;
labeled = 0;
both = 0;

states = Current Data Table() << Get Row States();
For( ii = 1, ii <= N Rows( states ), ii++,
    rs = As Row State( states[ii] ); 
    if (Excluded(rs) & Hidden(rs), hiddenAndExcluded++);
    if (Labeled(rs), labeled++);
    if (Excluded(rs) & Hidden(rs) & Labeled(rs), both++);
);

print(hiddenAndExcluded);
print(labeled);
print(both);
```

Comment: Hi! I tried pasting this in a new script that is embedded in the data table but nothing happens. I'll check if I can see where the error is. Thanks!

Comment: It works! I didn't know the answers should be seen in the log window. But is there a way to make the answers appear in something like a summary table? (Though it is not really needed. More of for elegance purposes.) Many thanks!.